# Doobers plopping out - how to do with a tween? Test case + screenshot attached

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, tween, gsap

Most of social games (like CastleVille (c) Zynga or Magic Land (c) Wooga) have *doobers* - coins, stars, etc. awarded to the player for some simple actions, like chopping a tree.

The doobers seem to execute several tweens:

1. First they plop out, bouncing. And their dimensions bounce too.
2. After that they fly up to the score bar in a bezier curve.

I have prepared a very simple test case and a screenshot for my question. The test case is in Flex, because that is what I've been using most recently, but my question is more general (ActionScript, Tween). I am using the [com.greensock.TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/) library.

**My problem:** I've figured out how to do the second, bezier part. But I don't know, how to do the first, bouncing part?

[image]

**MyApp.mxml** (doesn't have to be Flex, can be Flash):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               applicationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;
            import com.greensock.TweenMax;
            import com.greensock.easing.Cubic;

            private function init():void {
                var g:Graphics = myComp.graphics;
                g.clear();
                g.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, myComp.width, myComp.height);
                g.endFill();                
            }           

            private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var star:SpriteVisualElement = new Star();
                star.x = event.localX;
                star.y = event.localY;
                myComp.addChild(star);

                TweenMax.to(star, 1, {
                    delay: 2,
                    ease:  Cubic.easeOut,
                    bezier: [
                        {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: Math.max(event.localY, myComp.height/2)}, 
                        {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: 0}
                    ]
                });
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    

    <mx:UIComponent id="myComp" width="100%" height="100%" click="handleClick(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

**Star.fxg:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- fxg/star.fxg -->
<fxg:Graphic xmlns:fxg="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008" version="2">    
    <fxg:Path x="9.399" y="10.049" data="M 82.016 78.257 L 51.895 69.533 L 27.617 89.351 L 26.621 58.058 L 0.231 41.132 L 29.749 30.52 L 37.714 0.241 L 56.944 24.978 L 88.261 23.181 L 70.631 49.083 Z">
        <fxg:fill>
            <fxg:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </fxg:fill>
        <fxg:stroke>
            <fxg:SolidColorStroke 
                caps="none" 
                color="#4769C4" 
                joints="miter" 
                miterLimit="4" 
                weight="20"/>
        </fxg:stroke>
    </fxg:Path>
</fxg:Graphic>
```

Also I wonder, how to add a "Polaroid camera flash" effect at the very end?

**UPDATE:**

With LondonDrugs_MediaServices help (thank you!) the doobers squeeze and jump now (the code is below), but I still have 3 open issues:

1. How to run the flyTween on mouse over event?
2. How to add the "polaroid blitz" tween at the very end?
3. Don't know how to remove the mouse over handler at the end - since it is an anonimous closure

Also I've posted my question at [the GreenSock forum](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/6498-doobers-plopping-out-how-to-squeeze-and-bounce-at-the-same-time/).

Thank you for any hints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               applicationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.greensock.TweenMax;
            import com.greensock.easing.Bounce;
            import com.greensock.easing.Cubic;
            import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

            private function init():void {
                var g:Graphics = myComp.graphics;
                g.clear();
                g.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, myComp.width, myComp.height);
                g.endFill();                
            }           

            private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var star:SpriteVisualElement = new Star();
                star.x = event.localX;
                star.y = event.localY;
                myComp.addChild(star);

                TweenMax.to(star, 2, {
                    bezier: [
                        {x:star.x + 10, y:star.y - 20, scaleX: 1,   scaleY: 1}, 
                        {x:star.x + 20, y:star.y + 20, scaleX: 1.2, scaleY: .8}, 
                        {x:star.x + 20, y:star.y + 30, scaleX: 1,   scaleY: 1}], 
                    orientToBezier: false, 
                    ease: Bounce.easeOut
                });

                var flyTween:TweenMax = TweenMax.to(star, 1, {
                    delay: 10,
                    ease:  Cubic.easeOut,
                    bezier: [
                        {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: Math.max(event.localY, myComp.height/2)}, 
                        {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: 0}
                    ],
                    onComplete: function():void {
                        myComp.removeChild(star);
                        // XXX how to remove the mouse over handler here?
                    }
                });

                star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
                    // XXX how to force flyTween to execute right now, without the delay?
                    flyTween.complete();
                });
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    

    <mx:UIComponent id="myComp" width="100%" height="100%" click="handleClick(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

UPDATE2: Thank you LondonDrugs_MediaServices, here the updated screenshot + code again.

It is fun to play with the doobers already, however still have 2 minor issues:

1. Do I really have to kill the (delayed) fly tween? Can't I instead somehow modify its delay (set it to 0) on mouse over?
2. It would be nice to have that "camera flash" effect at the end. I just can't remember how it was done - some standard Flash MX effect...

[image]

**MyApp.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               applicationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.greensock.TweenMax;
            import com.greensock.easing.Bounce;
            import com.greensock.easing.Cubic;
            import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
            import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

            private function init():void {
                var g:Graphics = myComp.graphics;
                g.clear();
                g.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, myComp.width, myComp.height);
                g.endFill();                
            }           

            private function goFlyTween(star:DisplayObject, delay:Number = 0):void {
                TweenMax.to(star, 1, {
                    delay: delay,
                    ease:  Cubic.easeOut,
                    bezier: [
                        {x: myComp.width - star.width, 
                         y: Math.max(star.y, myComp.height/2)}, 
                        {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: 0}
                    ],
                    onComplete: function():void {
                        if(star.parent)
                            star.parent.removeChild(star);
                    }
                });
            }

            private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var star:SpriteVisualElement = new Star();
                star.filters = [
                    new GlowFilter(0xffffff, 1, 4, 4, 10, 2), 
                    new GlowFilter(0x0, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 10, 2)
                ];
                star.x = event.localX;
                star.y = event.localY;
                myComp.addChild(star);

                TweenMax.to(star, 2, {
                    bezier: [
                        {x:star.x + 10, y:star.y - 20, scaleX: 1,   scaleY: 1}, 
                        {x:star.x + 20, y:star.y + 20, scaleX: 1.2, scaleY: .8}, 
                        {x:star.x + 20, y:star.y + 30, scaleX: 1,   scaleY: 1}], 
                    orientToBezier: false, 
                    ease: Bounce.easeOut,
                    onComplete: goFlyTween,
                    onCompleteParams: [star, 3]
                });

                star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
                    // instead of killing + recreating, can't we just reset the delay?
                    TweenMax.killTweensOf(star);
                    goFlyTween(star);
                }, false, 0, true);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    

    <mx:UIComponent id="myComp" width="100%" height="100%" click="handleClick(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: First part can be done the same way as the second, use the TweenMax bezier tween, but set the easeOut as bounce instead of cubic.  You can also customize bounce to suite your needs

Comment: Yes, but how to make the doober fly in a parable and change its dimensions (squeeze - i.e. bigger width, smaller height) - all at the same time?

Comment: You could do a seperate tween for the scaleX property and use the elastic easing function.

Comment: You could also create a custom function that you call on the onUpdate parameter of your tween, and scale the x axis based off the position of the bounce tween.   It really depends on how you want it to look in the end

Comment: Or even easier, just adjust the scaleX on a bezier point(s) of your bounce

Comment: +1 for the doobers, the drawerings, and the question. Also curious to learn about the polaroid blitz. Can we have more like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same basic way you do the second part. Just use the Bounce easing function, and add some scaleX modifications to the tween:  (Naturally you'll need to set the x/y values accordingly for your scenario)

```
TweenMax.to(star, 3, {bezier:[{x:star.x + 20, y:star.y - 10, scaleX: 1}, {x:star.x + 40, y:star.y + 20, scaleX: 2}, {x:star.x + 40, y:star.y + 30, scaleX: 1}], orientToBezier:false, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
```

**EDIT**

For you additional questions in your edit:

I would recommend making a separate function for your flyTween, it's not necessary but in my opinion makes life cleaner.  A weak listener on your mouseOver handler will make it a non-issue, see the update in the code below.  I don't know what you mean by 'Poloroid Blitz' so you'll need to explain that further.

```
      private function goFlyTween(star:DisplayObject, delay:Number = 0):void {
           TweenMax.to(star, 1, {
               delay: delay,
               ease:  Cubic.easeOut,
               bezier: [
                   {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: Math.max(event.localY, myComp.height/2)}, 
                   {x: myComp.width - star.width, y: 0}
               ],
               onComplete: function():void {
                    if(star.parent){
                        star.parent.removeChild(star);
               }
           });
       }



       private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var star:SpriteVisualElement = new Star();
            star.x = event.localX;
            star.y = event.localY;
            myComp.addChild(star);

            TweenMax.to(star, 2, {
                bezier: [
                    {x:star.x + 10, y:star.y - 20, scaleX: 1,   scaleY: 1}, 
                    {x:star.x + 20, y:star.y + 20, scaleX: 1.2, scaleY: .8}, 
                    {x:star.x + 20, y:star.y + 30, scaleX: 1,   scaleY: 1}], 
                orientToBezier: false, 
                ease: Bounce.easeOut,
                onComplete: goFlyTween,
                onCompleteParams: [star, 3]
            });

            star.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,function(event:MouseEvent):void {
                TweenMax.killTweensOf(star);
                goFlyTween(star);
            },false,0,true); //use a weak listener (last parameter true on addEventListener), then you don't have to worry about removing the listener.  OR just don't use an anonymous function for this...
        }
```

For your bounce tween, tack on an onComplete parameter:

Comment: Though I've never played any the games mentioned so I have no real point of reference to your goal.

Comment: You should, they're very addicting and try to pull large sums of money out of your pocket ;-) Any advices on my updated questions please?

Comment: Makes sense with `star.parent`, thanks. By "polaroid" effect I mean there is an effect when the doober (star, coin, ...) are very light for a short moment of time - before they disappear, like in a camera flash effect. I wonder how to achieve it (some colors tween?)

Comment: Isn't it possible to enforce immediate execution of the delayed fly tween - instead of killing and recreating the whole tween anew?

Comment: you're killing the previous tween (bounce) if it's still in progress when it's time to fly to the score bar.   The poloroid effect is really easy with the colorMatrixFilter build into tween max:   colorMatrixFilter:{brightness:3} as one of your values would give a white washed looked.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're creating a new tween in memory regardless.  That killTweensOf is just making sure to stop the bounce (which is a different tween altogether than fly to one).  using a delay is actually less efficient - because that creates a timer in the background that to tick and it puts your tween in memory that much earlier.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've got a tip in GreenSock forum to use `flyTween.restart()` if I want to force the delayed tween to execute immediately.